# Slot to make VPN connection wifi but fast via cell?

Tags: vpn, windows-7

I am not sure why this is, but when I connect my business computer to my office VPN using my cell phone's hotspot, it takes only a few seconds.   Trying to accomplish the same with my WiFi can take 10-12 minutes.  Any ideas why?   My WiFi uses Google's DNS servers.

Once connected, everything works fine and is faster on WiFi than cell.  I just don't understand what is causing the initial connection delay.

This is a Windows 7 machine.

More info:  The windows 7 machine is an office PC that is using Cisco AnyConnect client.   So it is not native windows VPN.

Answer (score 1):

My wild guess: your WiFi has Windows trying one of its IPv6 tunneling techniques (Teredo, ISATAP, 6to4) but they don't actually work for some reason, leading to the system attempting to use IPv6 connectivity that is actually broken.

Your cell phone's hotspot, on the other hand, either has fully working IPv6 or it is set up to deny the IPv6 tunneling in such a way that Windows can detect IPv6 is definitely not available.

If you see an IPv6 tunnel interface listed as active when you run `ipconfig /all` in Command Prompt while connected to your WiFi, then this might be the reason.

If you don't need the IPv6 tunneling techniques, you can disable them by running a Command Prompt as an administrator, and entering these three commands:

```
netsh int ipv6 isatap set state disabled
netsh int ipv6 6to4 set state disabled
netsh interface teredo set state disable
```

Comment: thanks for the helpful response.  I am thinking along the same lines as you.  IP6 seems to be enabled throughout the network here but, as you said, something must be interfering with this somewhere so it must be back-peddling to IP4.   I'll do some more checking.   All my equipment in the house is pretty new and I do show IP6 addresses for DNS.  I'll keep working on it.  Thanks!

Comment: Ok IP6-Test.com shows IP6 isn't working.   It appears to be enabled in the router.  It shows a Temporary IPv6 address which seems strange.  But it also shows a permanent Link-Local IPV6 address.  Any thoughts?  I should also mention that this being a company PC, I am not authorized to use netsh.

Comment: Since IPv6 is apparently not working, you probably should try disabling it in your router for now. (In the future, you might re-enable it if your ISP improves the IPv6 situation...) Disabling IPv6 in the router should stop the router from announcing itself as an IPv6 gateway and name server, which might help things. The link-local IPv6 address alone should be harmless; the problem is probably something like the router announcing IPv6 support and then failing to actually provide working IPv6 connections over the internet.